# Removing Lines from a Json

Tags: json, swift

I'm trying to make an iOS Application as a project using a website called MTG Json as part of the database.

They provide an open source database for all cards printed in the game. This is how they format it.

```
 {"Air Elemental":{"layout":"normal","name":"Air Elemental","manaCost":"{3}{U}{U}","cmc":5,"colors":["Blue"],"type":"Creature — Elemental","types":["Creature"],"subtypes":["Elemental"],"text":"Flying","power":"4","toughness":"4","imageName":"air elemental","colorIdentity":["U"]},

  "Ancestral Recall":{"layout":"normal","name":"Ancestral Recall","manaCost":"{U}","cmc":1,"colors":["Blue"],"type":"Instant","types":["Instant"],"text":"Target player draws three cards.","mciNumber":"1","imageName":"ancestral recall","colorIdentity":["U"]},
```

What I would like to do is write a code that removes the first part of those lines

Removing "Ancestral Recall": or "Air Elemental": for ease of use.

Is there any simple way to do this? Or is there a better solution I am missing?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You didn't explain why you wanted to change the JSON. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Parse the JSON and access it as you would any dictionary/array

Comment: I'm doing this as a favor for a friend. He has always parsed files this way so I'm trying to make it easier for him. The way you've shown is the way he wants it. Were I trying to do this for myself, I'd try and find a way to parse if the way all of them did.

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't need to remove those lines as they are  the key for the objects provided in JSON format, instead of that just parse the JSON as it is and get the objects and here more specifically `NSDictionary` and by retrieving all keys of the dictionary you can get all the objects from it

Comment: If you need any further help just ask for it :)
I love to help.

Comment: I'm doing this as a favor for a friend. He has always parsed files this way so I'm trying to make it easier for him. Were I trying to do this for myself, I'd try and find a way to parse if the way all of them did.

Comment: Okay wish you a luck for it and if you get success please let us know about it if you fill so. Happy Coding... :)

Answer (score 1):

JSON is a key-value system. You use the key to get the value/object. If you remove the key, you cannot get the value. Actually, if a key is missing, the JSON parser will complain that it is not a valid JSON.

In your case, both objects are almost the same, they share a lot of common entries. You could create a global type, with empty entries and make it an array

```
{
    "Items": [{
        "layout": "normal",
        "name": "Air Elemental",
        "manaCost": "{3}{U}{U}",
        "cmc": 5,
        "colors": ["Blue"],
        "type": "Creature — Elemental",
        "types": ["Creature"],
        "subtypes": ["Elemental"],
        "text": "Flying",
        "power": "4",
        "toughness": "4",
        "imageName": "air elemental",
        "colorIdentity": ["U"]
    }, {
        "layout": "normal",
        "name": "Ancestral Recall",
        "manaCost": "{U}",
        "cmc": 1,
        "colors": ["Blue"],
        "type": "Instant",
        "types": ["Instant"],
        "text": "Target player draws three cards.",
        "mciNumber": "1",
        "imageName": "ancestral recall",
        "colorIdentity": ["U"]
    }]
}
```

That would remove one key as you still have to have a key for your dictionary. This is because you may create a second array of the same type, with a different name. You would need to have a way to make the difference between both arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I think he wants it like this. I parse everything like this, don't know how to fix your file though, sorry.

```
[{
        "layout": "normal",
        "name": "Ancestral Recall",
        "manaCost": "{U}",
        "cmc": 1,
        "colors": ["Blue"],
        "type": "Instant",
        "types": ["Instant"],
        "text": "Target player draws three cards.",
        "mciNumber": "1",
        "imageName": "ancestral recall",
        "colorIdentity": ["U"]
    }, {
        "layout": "normal",
        "name": "Ancestral Recall",
        "manaCost": "{U}",
        "cmc": 1,
        "colors": ["Blue"],
        "type": "Instant",
        "types": ["Instant"],
        "text": "Target player draws three cards.",
        "mciNumber": "1",
        "imageName": "ancestral recall",
        "colorIdentity": ["U"]
    }]
```

Comment: I'm doing this as a favor for a friend. He has always parsed files this way so I'm trying to make it easier for him. The way you've shown is the way he wants it. Were I trying to do this for myself, I'd try and find a way to parse if the way all of them did.